# asp.net Wizard control strange issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

Update:

There was actually a hidden panel with validator in the user control that was causing page not to be valid on the first postback. Consider this issue resolved.

This is first time I am using this control and it is behaving rather strange. I have to click on the "Next" button twice for it to move to the next step. I tried explicitly setting active index, using MoveTo etc. Nothing works. Here is the markup for the control. Anybody has any ideas why?

```
 <asp:Wizard ID="UserWizard" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0"
         StartNextButtonImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Default/images/buttons/continue.gif" StartNextButtonType="Image"
        StepNextButtonType="Image" StepNextButtonImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/buttons/continue.gif"
        FinishPreviousButtonImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/buttons/back.gif"
        FinishPreviousButtonType="Image" FinishCompleteButtonImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/buttons/save.gif"
        FinishCompleteButtonType="Image" CancelButtonType="Image" CancelButtonImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/buttons/back.gif"
        DisplaySideBar="false" >
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep Title="User Profile" ID="UserProfile" runat="server">
                <uhc:ctlUserProfileEdit ID="ctlUserProfileEdit" runat="server">
                </uhc:ctlUserProfileEdit>
                <br clear="all" />
                <div>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdResetPassword" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/buttons/resetpassword.gif" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSchools" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <uhc:ctlSchoolLocationSelector ID="ctlSchoolLocationSelector" runat="server" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep Title="Roles" ID="Roles" runat="server">
                <uhc:ctlPermissionInternal ID="ctlPermissionInternal1" runat="server"></uhc:ctlPermissionInternal>
                <uhc:ctlPermissionExternal ID="ctlPermissionExternal1" runat="server"></uhc:ctlPermissionExternal>
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this is what's causing it, but I find it strange that there is an UpdatePanel within the Wizard control, rather than the Wizard Control within the update panel.  This may be causing some strange behavior.

Can you change this and see if the problem resolves itself?